# Send new records in Rails DB to a browser page without refreshing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, websocket, long-polling

What is the best way for a browser to receive new records entered into a Rails DB, without having to refresh the page?

**Example**

I have a website with Rails as the backend.

On one page, I show a **post**. It has **comments** and **upvotes**.

Whenever a new **comment** or **upvote** is created, I want the browser to receive it in near real time and render it on to the page.

If it matters, my front-end is done in AngularJS.

Comment: This is not a simple task - you will need redis and additional node server. Have a read: http://liamkaufman.com/blog/2013/02/27/adding-real-time-to-a-restful-rails-app/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385158/rails-3-real-time-server-push http://www.slideshare.net/piotrkarbownik5/rails-4-server-sent-events

Comment: https://pusher.com/ this looks like an awesome solution instead of implementing it myself. $20 / month. (I don't work or have any relation to this company, just google searched)